Might my prime lens be broken?
I accidentally dropped my Sony SEL20F18G prime lens from a height of about 1 foot onto a linoleum floor. While the lens looks fine externally, I can feel slight movement inside when I turn it upside down. It feels like a component drops into place when I rotate it so that the mount end is on the table, and again if the front end is on the table.
Could this be a sign of internal damage or something to be concered about?

Certainly sounds like something inside it is broken.
But the proof of the pudding is in the eating. If it still takes good photos, it's probably okay. Would I keep using it as an amateur? Sure, because it would cost me a significant amount to even get it looked at. Would I rely on it if I were a professional photographer? No.
